# How to preview all type of uploaded files like pdf, csv, exel etc in next js without any package

Tags: reactjs, pdf, next.js13, react-pdf

I am creating a web app and there have a chat system. I want when i upload files like image, video, pdf, csv, exel, docs etc and send it to other person in chat then it should appear and he should able to preview it. I want to make it as like Slack App. And i want to make my custom solution so that i can make it as i want.

I already try react-file-viewer but there have problem that some files is not previewing. But when i upload that files in Slack app it previewed. So now i want to make my custom file viewer so that i can preview all type of files and i also can share it with community.